# pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError:- Element is available in the screen when scrolling down/up

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

My application screen has few regions/blocks/tabs/groups which are foldable, by default the first region is visible, to see the next region/blocks the user need to scroll down.
The application loads all its components at once, it doesn't do lazy loading while scrolling.

Code

```
dealer = contentPanel.child_window(auto_id="dealerid", control_type="Window")             
dealerName = dealer.child_window(auto_id="dealerid_lookupValue", control_type="DataItem")
dealerName.set_text("Car Dealer")
```

The Text field to enter dealer name contains a lookup button, inspect.exe gives the name of the text field as `dealerid_lookupValue`

While trying to access an element that is not visible, I get the below error

```
dealerName.set_text("Car Dealer")
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 379, in __getattribute__
    ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 261, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 436, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 222, in __get_ctrl
    ctrl = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**ctrl_criteria))
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 87, in find_element
    raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'auto_id': 'dealerid_lookupValue', 'control_type': 'DataItem', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo - 'Dealer for the case', , None>, 'backend': 'uia'}
```

This happens for any element that I try to access which is not visible.

I tried to navigate thru the regions/blocks/tabs, but that throws error similar error as ElementNotFound

Comment: This might be a problem walking the children. Current workaround is using .iter_children() generator that uses RawTreeWalker.

Comment: We have plans to use RawTreeWalker everywhere by default because some apps like specific Qt5 versions have problems with FindAll approach. It’s technically app side issue, but this is what we can do to choose default approach.